# Spring JPA force save

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have basic question but I cannot find the response for it.

As I see each time I change entity I have to save it.

But is there some way to enable autosave?

Comment: Dont you think some actual code and actual problem definition would help?

Answer (score 0):

If the methods you update the entity is marked with ***@Transactional*** annotation, you don't need to call **save** or **update** methods.

**Note that**, the entity must be fetched from DB to be maintained. If the entity has already created, you still need to use save method.